# How to set datetime as zaxis without error: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long for 3D plot

Tags: python, datetime, mplot3d

I am trying to plot a 3D image where z is time. 
When I try to set the zaxis label to Year, month I receive an error.

For this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(df85['Messwert'], df85['average_cux'], df85['Datum'],c=df85['code'], cmap="jet_r")
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%M'))
```

I got this error:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

Without the set zaxis code I get this image:

[image]

Thanks in advance!!!

[image]

at bottom of 'Datum':

```
Name: Datum, Length: 81, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

The overflow error occurs because Matplotlib's DateFormatter fails to plot `np.datetime64` data directly, which should be the case with your data. You need to explicitly convert your dates to `datetime.date` objects.

Please have a look at this :
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html

The overflow error occurs because Matplotlib's DateFormatter fails to plot `np.datetime64` data directly, which should be the case with your data. You need to explicitly convert your dates to `datetime.date` objects.

Please have a look at this :
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html

Edit :
This might be useful to you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, DateFormatter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# a test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': np.array([str(datetime(2020,3,30).date()+timedelta(x+1))+' 00:00:00' for x in range(200)], dtype='object'),
    'sales': np.random.randint(low=1, high=200, size=200),
    '%sales in US' : 30 * np.random.random_sample(size=200) + 20
})

# appropriate type conversions
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(date2num)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.scatter3D(df['sales'], df['%sales in US'], df['date'], c=df['date'], cmap="jet_r")
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%M'))
plt.xlabel('sales', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('%sales in US', fontsize=16)
ax.set_zlabel('date', fontsize=16) 
plt.show()
```

Output : https://imgur.com/a/WXM07it.jpg

Comment: Hi thank you for this quick response. However, if i convert to object with `df85['Datum'] = df85.Datum.astype('O')`. When I run the plot code I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'Timestamp'

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>`

Comment: Can you post how your ```df85['Datum']``` looks like?

Comment: Hi, yes just posted in question. Thanks

Comment: Without proper context and code, it would be difficult to identify the problem. However, I have attached a code snippet trying to generate a similar problem. This might be of use to you.

Comment: Hi, thanks I will have a look I will see if I can upload my data if it doesn't work. Thank you !